# R - Predict(), renaming columns, and " had 10 rows but variables found have 20 rows "

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, glm

From other threads I've seen people provide solutions that are specific to exact problems, but I don't understand the underlying reason of what's going wrong.

I do...

```
modTest = glm( trainLabels[,1] ~ A + B + C + 
           D + E + F + G + 
            H + I, family=binomial(link='logit') )
```

The above is 20 labels, and 9 vectors each with 20 values.

I then try to predict on 10 unseen examples.  This is 10 rows, 9 features, same order.

```
preds = predict( modTest, testFeatures )
```

I get the error...

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 20 rows
```

Edit : Simplified, removed long feature names, etc.

```
> names(trainFeatures)
[1] "Neg"  "Pos"  "Num"  "UN"   "UNA"  "UNUA" "UP"   "UPA"  "UPUA"
names(testFeatures)
[1] "Neg"  "Pos"  "Num"  "UN"   "UNA"  "UNUA" "UP"   "UPA"  "UPUA"
```

> 

Edit: Dputs...

To use the dputs, what I did was...

```
 modTest = glm( trainLabels[,1] ~ as.matrix(trainFeatures) )
 preds = predict( modTest, testFeatures )

Warning message:
'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 20 rows
```

Not sure why I'm getting that warning still.

```
  dput(trainLabels)
    structure(list(Neg = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Pos = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Num = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UN = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UNA = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UNUA = c(1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UP = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UPA = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), UPUA = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Neg", 
"Pos", "Num", "UN", "UNA", "UNUA", "UP", "UPA", "UPUA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
    dput(trainFeatures)
    structure(list(Neg = c(39106, 44664, 114130, 26526, 22122, 19175, 
    29438, 17741, 17589, 20666, 66024, 168336, 86283, 74826, 88998, 
    75756, 16041, 17087, 15235, 16659), Pos = c(16129, 21064, 57730, 
    10314, 18105, 16837, 19300, 16873, 13681, 18414, 27148, 120497, 
    60031, 49016, 59250, 36264, 15786, 16315, 14556, 16057), Num = c(82994, 
    121367, 306842, 55458, 69148, 63167, 85891, 58674, 55874, 67505, 
    152475, 427106, 221043, 190043, 223744, 177388, 51657, 54883, 

    48378, 54115), UN = c(32343, 35433, 74835, 22271, 17686, 15498, 
    22416, 14238, 14078, 16800, 54636, 121211, 68079, 59913, 70884, 
    61408, 13221, 14114, 12647, 13487), UNA = c(95.1499874, 95.0987263, 
    95.3942596, 95.5444865, 113.1263844, 112.3827424, 111.2684513, 
    113.2184128, 112.4336258, 114.1739588, 113.5086472, 111.6715378, 
    112.2842917, 111.9490612, 113.6465561, 111.5254103, 112.2179148, 
    111.2933853, 112.9056117, 113.1511475), UNUA = c(-94.4280737, 
    -94.5019854, -94.9246672, -95.0379578, -113.2247115, -112.3497485, 
    -111.1631387, -113.2051289, -112.1822898, -114.0431466, -113.7435412, 
    -111.6226818, -112.4077795, -111.9886653, -113.8072166, -111.6138577, 
    -113.0855995, -112.3075275, -114.2628431, -114.1088453), UP = c(10384, 
    13015, 24470, 6891, 13445, 12852, 13008, 13093, 9878, 14272, 
    14938, 77058, 40595, 32518, 39889, 21424, 8322, 8451, 7440, 8071
    ), UPA = c(58.6289931, 57.73430079, 61.3480343, 57.8297594, 62.1749994, 
    65.1140073, 62.619361, 63.6791219, 63.412582, 65.1856906, 45.18365794, 
    71.32918265, 56.04488913, 58.13008276, 53.16603128, 50.36242011, 
    64.6742956, 64.0982314, 63.4422878, 64.24099034), UPUA = c(88.9216885, 
    88.3012858, 88.1996008, 88.9910129, 91.0232669, 89.4524702, 91.9122816, 
    89.8549338, 90.6487273, 88.2063941, 99.9573821, 109.9128868, 
    103.7989926, 104.0274764, 103.4209936, 101.5065677, 85.8110039, 
    87.0786241, 86.1020646, 86.8835026)), .Names = c("Neg", "Pos", 
    "Num", "UN", "UNA", "UNUA", "UP", "UPA", "UPUA"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L), class = "data.frame")
    dput(testLabels)
    structure(list(Neg = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pos = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Num = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), UN = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UNA = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UNUA = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UP = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UPA = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), UPUA = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Neg", 
"Pos", "Num", "UN", "UNA", "UNUA", "UP", "UPA", "UPUA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
    > dput(testFeatures)
    structure(list(Neg = c(51404, 32447, 24642, 95979, 15743, 90843, 
    13813, 11496, 12871, 13546), Pos = c(23350, 13525, 19941, 49984, 
    10867, 64404, 13324, 11302, 12918, 13118), Num = c(121342, 68160, 
77219, 248890, 49259, 232645, 43707, 35674, 40734, 42979), UN = c(40766, 
27363, 19590, 71772, 12615, 71496, 11529, 9739, 10810, 11346), 
    UNA = c(95.2486872, 93.4642772, 111.3853297, 112.6770471, 
    110.0845355, 113.6696598, 111.8409793, 116.0476022, 120.3481302, 
    111.9496978), UNUA = c(-94.6150698, -92.5605373, -111.1994432, 
    -112.4947319, -109.7130777, -113.8083912, -112.5678322, -116.5407619, 
    -121.4756386, -113.4991191), UP = c(14285, 9043, 14862, 31626, 
    7491, 43903, 7021, 5559, 6149, 6789), UPA = c(61.25585053, 
    62.6231081, 64.191128, 64.6397131, 63.4911744, 58.4792454, 
    63.5063289, 60.5667637, 60.3857056, 64.1569975), UPUA = c(88.4605419, 
    88.2790682, 90.0217465, 88.8441004, 91.0222662, 105.0494229, 
    85.8914139, 86.7685668, 84.8304901, 86.9786109)), .Names = c("Neg", 
"Pos", "Num", "UN", "UNA", "UNUA", "UP", "UPA", "UPUA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Without data, it is hard to reproduce and pinpoint the problem. Can you at least post output of `names` for `testFeatures`?

Comment: Sure, I editted it because I thought it made it confusing. Ill edit in above.

Comment: This type of problem almost always happens when you fit a model with one set of variables and try to predict with non-matching list. Or, if there are categorical variables in the data, and the train set does not have the same factor levels as the test set, etc. etc.

Comment: @Gopala, Zheyuan Adding dputs now.

Comment: :) That simplified one shows perfect match. What can we do with it now? You need to check levels of factors, `str` of fit object and `names`, etc...

Comment: @Gopala Added code showing exactly what Im doing now too. Just two lines. Removes any ambiguity my original statement may have had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ran the code with all the data you provided and get the results just fine. Here is the model fit:

```
modTest = glm(trainLabels[,1] ~ Neg + Pos + Num + 
                   UN + UNA + UNUA + UP + 
                   UPA + UPUA, family=binomial(link='logit'),
              data = trainFeatues)
```

Here are the predicted values on test data:

```
predict( modTest, testFeatures)
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
 4.6711576 -1.3572345 -2.0639104 18.7625539 -7.6961149  0.4317324 -0.8983256 -8.2052158 
         9         10 
-1.5968013 10.8357174
```

NOTE: an alternative specification can be like this:

```
modTest = glm(trainLabels[,1] ~ trainFeatues$Neg + trainFeatues$Pos +
                   trainFeatues$Num + trainFeatues$UN + trainFeatues$UNA +
                   trainFeatues$UNUA + trainFeatues$UP + trainFeatues$UPA + 
                   trainFeatues$UPUA, family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

However, the fit model is as follows:

```
modTest$coefficients
      (Intercept)  trainFeatues$Neg  trainFeatues$Pos  trainFeatues$Num   trainFeatues$UN 
     4.027803e+01      8.874801e-04     -3.000123e-03      1.277138e-04     -4.521793e-04 
 trainFeatues$UNA trainFeatues$UNUA   trainFeatues$UP  trainFeatues$UPA trainFeatues$UPUA 
    -1.519463e+01     -1.480503e+01      2.930261e-03      4.741432e-01     -3.690940e-01
```

When you feed the train data to predict, this is causing problems since the features fit above are not matching the new data being fed to predict. Leading to:

```
predict( modTest, testFeatures)
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
 0.21651890  3.23450117 -2.16298672 -0.06949967 -0.91026504 -0.91484739 -1.69209826 
          8           9          10          11          12          13          14 
-2.45603982 -6.35855600 -1.84871546 -0.25027815  2.72625440 -0.50422297 -1.76701963 
         15          16          17          18          19          20 
 0.05033351  0.65101666  0.27680835  1.79176029  6.79618311 -0.16186455 
Warning message:
'newdata' had 10 rows but variables found have 20 rows
```

Comment: Okay, so I'd like to clarify here what's going on then. Tell me if I am correct please.  In glm, the first argument is the label.  The arguments after ~ are the NAMES you're going to use, but not data itself.  Then the data is required to have those feature names in the dataset you apply (here: trainFeatures).  Furthermore, the test set also requires those names.